# How to get a list of installed apps in iOS11 using Swift 4?

Tags: swift4, ios11

I want to get list of the apps installed on the users device in iOS 11 using Swift 4. But I'm unable to find a place where such functionality is documented. Is it even possible in iOS 11 ?

Comment: [You should read up on Apple App-Sandboxing to gain a better understanding of how things stand](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/)

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to get list of all the installed apps, perhaps you can try with particular app's deep link and `canOpenURL(_:)`

like if you want to check if whatsapp is installed or not the device then you can try with url "whatsapp://" or if you want to check whether fb is installed or not then you might try "fb://" with `canOpenURL(_:)` and it will return yes/no based on the result found.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @milan-manwar, you could use `canOpenURL(_:)`. However this API has been deprecated in iOS 10, because it can be used to spy on users. The whole thing is described for example at [this blog](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/). Twitter had used this API [before to spy on people](https://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2014/11/26/twitter-is-tracking-users-installed-apps-for-ad-targeting/). That's why you really should not do this.

Answer (score -1):

try below link for get list of all installed application with information in iPhone device.

https://github.com/profburke/AppLister

Comment: This Project worked only in simulator not in IOS device. LSApplicationWorkspace always return 0 in IOS device.